# Approach to mapping dictionary database tables to models in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dictionary, orm

lacking a fellow programmer to talk over the right approach for my problem, I decided to ask you. What is your preferred approach of mapping dictionary tables to a model in MVC paradigm, regardless of the MVC framework / environment you are using?

My problem is I have a couple of database tables that only serve as dictionaries and are related to other tables as foreign keys. A good example would be a table `request` having a `status_id` where statuses are kept in a separate `status` table.

Now, the latter table needs to be mapped to a model on the code-side of the application. I can either:

1. Define all the statuses as constants so they can be referenced in the code without poking those dreaded 'magic numbers' here and there. However, any change to the dictionary (database-side) would require a code modification.
2. Omit the `status` table at all and just define meaningful constant to be used across the code. Pros: one place to rule them all. Cons: all changes require diving into the code, now the database features 'magic numbers' not really being foreign keys
3. Try to translate statuses into the model automagically, adding a field like 'const_name' to the 'statuses' table and them creating the constants on the fly while loading the model. This one seems to have the most sense for me.

Would you mind to share your usual approach to this issue?

Best,
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

If it's just going to be a set of constants that are contained in the database instead of code, you could have a static class load the `status` constants for everyone else to use. That way there's no duplication between db and code, and no magic numbers.

edit: since it's a static class, you could have it lazy load the constants. Don't hit the database until the first time someone asks for a status value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you going to change it often it's better to go with table. Otherwise static class is fine (for example no point having table to store sex, or list of states).